# How to calculate local rotation to keep text upright?

Tags: rotation, three.js

I have text on the screen that always faces the user and remains upright with the following code (this is working):

```js
object.lookAt(camera.position); 
               object.rotation.x = camera.rotation.x; 
               object.rotation.y = camera.rotation.y;
               object.rotation.z = camera.rotation.z;
```

Now, after a button has rotated the scene by 90 degrees about the y-axis,

```js
target = new THREE.Vector3(camera.position.z, camera.position.y, -camera.position.x);


object.lookAt(target);
```

So the text is facing the user as desired, but I can't figure out how to calculate the object rotation to keep the text vertical as I rotate the scene around with trackball controls:

```js
object.rotation.x = ??
object.rotation.y = ??
object.rotation.z = ??
```

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know which library you are using. Usually LookAt has an optional argument to specify an *up* vector.

Comment: r52, how do i get "up" correct?

Comment: you should take the up vector of the camera

Comment: i tried lookAt(target, [], camera.up), doesnt keep it upright when i move with trackball controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `THREE.OrbitControls` instead.

Then, in your render loop:

```
object.quaternion.copy( camera.quaternion );
```

three.js r.69

Comment: i tried this but then the object became the focus of my camera

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560735/three-sj-rotation-sending-info-via-network-not-fit?noredirect=1#comment133321728_75560735 , How to get degrees for individual axis local rotation ?